# Calling a function defined deep inside angularjs without dom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm dealing with some legacy code which looks like this:

```
angular.module("controllers.createEvent", []).controller("createEventItem", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "dialogService", "mainSvc", "eventSvc", "rulesSvc", "templateSvc", "notificationSvc", "syncSvc", "$log",
    function($rootScope, $scope, dialogService, mainSvc, eventSvc, rulesSvc, templateSvc, notificationSvc, syncSvc, $log) {
        //...snip...
        createEvent: function() {
            var timezone = $scope.crtParams.myObj.itemType !== 300 ? ...snip...
            var location = $scope.crtParams.location;
            var name = $scope.crtParams.name;
            var start = $scope.crtParams.start;

            //complex business logic 
            //ultimately saving to a window.indexedDB

            //...snip...
        }
        //...snip...
    }]
);
```

It seems to me that the business logic is nested inside this angular structure which is strongly tied to the DOM. What I want to do is insert an array of items by calling createEvent(). Ideally I'm hoping I can write code such as this:

```
var myImportedData = getDataSomehow();
for(var i=0; i<myImportedData.length; i++) {
    angular.createEvent(  
         myImportedData[i].Name
        ,myImportedData[i].Start
        ,myImportedData[i].End
        ,myImportedData[i].etc...
        ,myImportedData[i].etc...
    )
}
```

My goal here is to not rewrite the code written inside of `createEvent()` instead just call the existing code. Obviously I could just go straight to the database and perhaps reload the page, but the business logic is a little hairy and I'd rather not go that route if possible.

Is this possible? Perhaps I'll need to create a bunch of temporary DOM elements that are never placed on the page? Is this typical of angular code? I would have expected/hoped that the BL and save methods would reside in separate code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like this code should be extracted to a `service`, or `factory. If it's only part of that controller, there's not going to be a good (read: not hackey) way (nor should there be, as this really trashes MVC/MV* principles) to utilize it outside of that controller.

Comment: Ultimately the code can only do an insert to the database though a single set of DOM controls. If someone wanted to add another widget to the webpage duplicating this functionality it would be impossible as is - right?. Or if someone wanted to add another data source as input to the database (which is my case) then this too is impossible - right? Point being I believe this code is badly written or at least not future proof.  What I'm getting at is that I believe I should discourage this sort of code in the future for these reasons. - would you agree?

Comment: I would agree. Any business logic like this should absolutely be abstracted away from the controllers to some type of service.

Comment: What if I were to duplicate the dom, hide it, and then duplicate the code. Then build my loop to set the values, and simulate a click event... I mean that's what we are talking about here. So either bite the bullet and rewrite all of it, or hack the DOM to get it to conform to the code. (thanks so much for your help, btw, this is exactly the conversation I was looking for)

Comment: I mean, I can't stop you, but it's certainly not the "angular" way. And it sounds like a nightmare to maintain. But yes I suspect you could craft an element that reuses that controller (not sure if that's problematic, it'd need some testing), slap it into your `ng-app` container and simulate an event.

Comment: Yes I agree. Thank you for your insight!!

Comment: If you do go that way, you'll need to look into `$compile` to make angular aware of DOM modifications via JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a controller using the `$controller` service.

```
var myScope = $rootScope.$new();

var myVm = $controller("createEventItem", {$scope: myScope});
```

This will create an instance of the `createEventItem` controller with `$scope` injected with a scope that is a child of `$rootScope`.

For more information, see [AngularJS $controller Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

---

The example code can be placed in a run block.

```
angular.module("myApp", ["controllers.createEvent"])
    .run(function($rootScope, $controller) {

         var myScope = $rootScope.$new();

         var myVm = $controller("createEventItem", {$scope: myScope});

});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am not following: `$rootScope`, `$scope`, `$controller` are not defined.